# Density vs Mass density

Tags: mass, terminology, definition, density

I want to know the significant differences between
["Density"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) and "Mass Density"

I read somewhere that 'Mass Density' comes under 'Density' and generally used for linear objects probably.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density

Comment: I want a simple but precise explanation..wikipedia provides history/biography/geography etc. etc. of everything.

Comment: Mass density is mass per volume, kg per cubic metre. Other types of densities would be another quantity per volume.

Comment: Density is also Mass/Volume(Kg/m³)...then difference ?

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope this helps out your doubt.

Comment: -1. Not clear, and no research effort. If you want a precise definition, you have to provide a context in which these terms are being used.

Comment: @sammy I got my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several types of density.

- [Mass density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density)  $[\mathrm{kg/m^3}]$,
- [charge density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_density) $[\mathrm{C/m^3}]$,
- [carrier density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_carrier_density) (or other types of quantity density) $[\mathrm{1/m^3}]$,
- etc.

They all describe how much there is of something per "space".

The word *density* is just the common "category", so to speak. When you say *density* alone, it will most likely be implied which kind you mean. Most often it implies *mass density*, but not always.

Note that you can also run into lower dimensional densities.

- Volumetric (3D) density is something per $\mathrm m^3$ as above,
- [area density or surface density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_density) (2D) is something per $\mathrm m^2$ and
- [linear density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_density) (1D) is something per $\mathrm m$.

You will often see combinations such as *volumetric mass density* (being $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$) or *surface charge density* (being $\mathrm{C/m^2}$) and so on. As before, the dimension is often implied. You rarely hear *volumetric mass density* but more often only *mass density* or just *density*.